# Spring HandlerMethodArgumentResolver for the POST requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

just one question. Is it possible to use Spring HandlerMethodArgumentResolver for POST requests?
If it is, please share some examples or links with an explanation.
Thanks in advance